# How do I only commit a subrepo's changes?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

I have a master repo, which has some changes I do not want to commit.

I have a subrepo, which has changes *that have already been committed*.

I want to commit the changes subrepo revision in my master repo, without committing the changes to the files in the master repo.

I cannot seem to do this. I can't commit `.hgsubstate`, and making a trivial change to a file to commit that does not commit the subrepo changes to the master repo.

Comment: If your modified files are named `foo` and `bar`, have you tried doing `hg ci -S -X foo -X bar`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the name of the subrepo itself to commit and Mercurial will update `.hgsubstate` and commit it.

```
ry4an@four:~$ hg init main
ry4an@four:~$ cd main
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg init sub
ry4an@four:~/main$ echo sub = sub > .hgsub
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg add .hgsub
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg commit
ry4an@four:~/main$ cd sub
ry4an@four:~/main/sub$ echo text > afile
ry4an@four:~/main/sub$ hg commit -Am first-in-sub
adding afile
ry4an@four:~/main/sub$ cd ..
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg status
ry4an@four:~/main$ echo text > dont-commit-me
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg add dont-commit-me
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg status
A dont-commit-me
ry4an@four:~/main$ cat .hgsubstate
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 sub
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg commit -m 'subrepo only' sub
ry4an@four:~/main$ hg status
A dont-commit-me
ry4an@four:~/main$ cat .hgsubstate
dec5eaa9e22cd0a05cbba3ba02fdb0e1f243e07e sub
```

Note that the file in main `dont-commit-me` never got committed, but the `.hgsubstate` was updated.

Comment: That did the trick. I can't believe I didn't think to try that!

Comment: This is a little misleading, since `dont-commit-me` wouldn't have been committed anyway.  If it had been added, then the argument to `commit` would make a difference.  (I defer to Ry4an, though, as I know he is a Mercurial master.)

Comment: You're right, @harpo .  I should've  added it for it to be a better example.

Comment: In Hg (without a dummy file), I am getting "nothing changed". When I add a dummy file I get an error "uncommitted changes in subrepository". Seems like failed use-case handling..